# py2exe - missing module FileDialog after compiling Tkinter gui executable

Tags: python-2.7, compilation, tkinter, py2exe, setup.py

My question is much the same as this already answered question([Missing tkinter attributes after converting to py2exe executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933005/missing-tkinter-attributes-after-converting-to-py2exe-executable)). But it relates to python 2.7, which uses Tkinter, instead of tkinter.

I am basically having the same issue running my executable after compiling.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "gui.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "six.pyc", line 199, in load_module
  File "six.pyc", line 113, in _resolve
  File "six.pyc", line 80, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named FileDialog
```

But as I am using Tkinter with python 2.7 it means I can not do:

```
from tkinter import FileDialog
```

I have tried using

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
```

and

```
import tkFileDialog
```

but none have worked. Am I facing having to upgrade python to 3 just to be able to properly compile Tkinter? Or is there a workaround I'm missing?

This is my current setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import py2exe
import sys
import matplotlib

sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\redist\\x86\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT",
           glob(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*'))]
data_files.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())

setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    windows=['main.py'],
    packages=[''],
    name='ZLA',
    version='0.1 beta',
    description='Troubleshooter.',
    requires=['matplotlib', 'PIL', 'py2exe']
)
```

I have tried to specify tkFileDialog in options: includes: but still no luck :(

```
options={'py2exe': {'includes': ['Tkinter', 'tkFileDialog']}, }
```

UPDATE:

I found the answer after some investigating. You can actually just

```
import FileDialog
```

UPDATE2:

If you want to avoid the "unused import" feedback some debuggers and ide's give you, you can add the package FileDialog to the packages dictionary of py2exe in stead

```
options={'py2exe': {'packages': ['FileDialog']},}
```

Perhaps someone can help clarify why either is more appropriate?

Comment: Update 2 worked very well for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using "includes" use "packages" and only specify the package, in this case 'Tkinter'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately your answer does not seem to work for me. I get the same importerror

Comment: I believe the problem is that FileDialog was/is a seperate package from Tkinter, I have just tested your solution using FileDialog instead of Tkinter in packages, and was able to compile. I will update the question, and I thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)